# win 2008 as terminal server with multiple IPs running win 7 in it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

i have been given a task to build up a system using win 2008 r2. So the task is:

1) Everything running on only one machine with win 2008 r2

2) Set up terminal server with multiple IP addresses, so each user will have his own IP to log in (Remote Desktop) and to browse internet. For instance John will log in via 1.1.1.1 and when he browses internet from his RD, his IP will be 1.1.1.1. And user George will log in via 2.2.2.2. And they can't interchange.

3) The hardest part is, they should log in to win 7 through win 2008 terminal service. Boss mentioned, that win 7 will be running inside(or somehow) of win 2008. He also said "only one copy" of windows 7 for everyone. So he wont buy more licenses. No any virtual machines around, everything should be in one. So he can control the sessions and etc.

My thoughts was to set up bunch of virtual machines with dedicated IPs for each user. But he said big NO.  If this could be linux, I would use Linux-KVM. But with windows I'm very confused...

Please, guys, any clue how to perform this task will be very appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, you can't use Windows 7 that way.  You only get one login to a Windows 7 machine at a time.  If you have one license for Windows 7, you get one machine, so unless folks are not using it simultaneously, you can't do that part of the request.

You can use Windows 2008 that way, of course.  If you are using terminal services, you can also have multiple inbound IPs for users to connect to so that part's doable.  But not really helpful - the interesting part of an inbound connection is not the server IP but the client IP address, which is going to be logged when they login.  So you can skip that part, really.

So assuming we're talking about Windows 2008 here, there is no way to directly tell Windows "anytime this user connects outbound us this IP as the source IP."  The only way I can think of to make this work would be two parts:

1. Set up outbound proxy server(s) of some kind.
2. Configure each user's profile on the terminal server to use a different proxy server/address to connect outbound.

Comment: Sounds like the boss doesn't know the difference between virtualisation, VDI, or their own ass.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is called Virtual Desktop Infrastructure, or VDI, and [Microsoft has solutions to help](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/virtualization/operating-system/default.aspx).

The licensing part of your question is off-topic. You're going to have a hard time making this happen legally without making a significant investment in licenses.